# How to correctly send python email with attachment and HTML body with alternate plain text body

Tags: python, html, email, text, attachment

I am using python to send an email with an HTML body and an attachment. I also want to include a plain text email body for email clients that do not display HTML. The code sample from my application below seems to work in many cases but I have noticed that in the IOS email client that the attachment does not appear.

If I just send the email as HTML then everything seems to work but if possible I want to provide an alternate plain text body. Is there anything I am missing in my code to send both the HTML and plain text email body correctly.

Any advice much appreciated.

```
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

# Mail server settings
MAIL_SMTP_SERVER = "smtp.gmail.com"
MAIL_PORT = 465
MAIL_USERNAME = '***'
MAIL_PASSWORD = '***'

email_to = '*@***.com'
email_from = '#@###.com'
email_subject = 'Email test'
email_body_html = '''
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Email Body</h1>
                <p>Here is some text</p>
            </body>
        </html>
        '''
email_body_plaintext = 'This is the plain text body'
path='./test_doc.pdf'
name='doc.pdf'


# Create the message
mime_message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
mime_message["From"] = email_from
mime_message["To"] = email_to
mime_message["Subject"] = email_subject

# Add  file attachment to the message
with open(path, "rb") as file_to_read:
    file_attachment = MIMEApplication(file_to_read.read())

file_attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", f"attachment; filename= {name}")
mime_message.attach(file_attachment)

# Attach the plain text body
mime_message.attach(MIMEText(email_body_plaintext, "plain"))

# Attach the HTML body
mime_message.attach(MIMEText(email_body_html, "html"))

# Get the mime message into string format
email_string = mime_message.as_string()

# Connect to the SMTP server and Send Email
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(MAIL_SMTP_SERVER, MAIL_PORT, context=context) as server:
    server.login(MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(email_from, email_to, email_string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multipart/alternative` can only contain a text part and an HTML part.  If you want to have an additional attachment, you need a more complicated structure:

- `multipart/mixed`

  - `multipart/alternative`

    - `text/plain`
    - `text/html`
  - `application/pdf`

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure how to implement that structure though. Do I need to add an new variable and set it to application/pdf; then attach my attachment to that; and then attach that new variable to the original message?

Comment: You are creating the original message as `MimeMultipart('alternative')`.  You need to create the outer shell as `MimeMultipart('mixed')`, then add your `MimeMultipart('alternative')` to that, then add your PDF attachment to the outershell as well.

Comment: Thanks for that. I restructured the way my message is created and all working.